# Numerically solving for fixed points in 2D

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following four functions

```
u_h = u_h(J_l, J_h)
u_l = u_l(J_l, J_h)
J_l = J_l(u_h, u_l)
J_h = J_h(u_h, u_l)
```

If you will, let `u = [u_l, u_h]`, and `J = [J_l, J_h]`. Then the stationary state to the system defined by the previous equations can be defined through the two vector-valued functions `u`, `J`:

```
u_0 = [u_l_0, u_h_0]: 
u_0 = u(J(u_0))
```

Similarly, I need to check whether `J(u(J_0)) = J`.

This is a conceptual question and the code behind these functions is not really simplifyable to make it worthwhile to have a reasonable working example.

Here's what I've been doing so far:

```
# create a grid for test-values u
u = np.linspace(0.0001, 0.3, 200)
GridUL, GridUH = np.meshgrid(u, u, indexing='ij')

# J = [JL, JH] would be what I called "J" previously
JL = JSteadyState(GridUL, GridUH, thisType='low')
JH = JSteadyState(GridUL, GridUH, thisType='high')
UL2, UH2 = uSteadyState(JL, Param), uSteadyState(JH, Param)

# check for fixed points in both variables
err = 1e-3
fixedPointL = abs(UL2-GridUL) < err
fixedPointH = abs(UH2-GridUH) < err
fixedPointH & fixedPointH
```

How can **efficiently** I check `UL2`, `UH2` against `GridUL`, `GridUH` to find the **fixed points** (plural)?

My approach so far depends much on try-and-error and the grid sizes. `scipy.optimize.root` appears to be focussed on simple roots and not more complicated fixed-point problems. I could write the fixed-point problem as a root problem, but I imagine that this would be quite inefficient. How should I progress with this?

Comment: I came across many multidimensional problems of finding fixed points ... and I solved all of them with `root-finders`. Finding fixed points is a `root-finding` problem. Therefore, I recommend you not to try to reinvent the wheel but to try different `root-solvers` (not all of them are appropriate to a specific problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using [scipy.optimize.fixed_point](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fixed_point.html):

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def func(x):
    x0, x1 = x
    # J = [JL, JH] would be what I called "J" previously
    JL = JSteadyState(x0, x1, thisType='low')
    JH = JSteadyState(x0, x1, thisType='high')
    UL2 = uSteadyState(JL, Param)
    UH2 = uSteadyState(JH, Param)
    return np.array([UL2, UH2])

err = 1e-3
guess = [0.1, 0.1]
fixedPointL, fixedPointH = optimize.fixed_point(func, guess, xtol=err)
```

Note however that this does not restrict `x` and `y` to the domain `(0.0001,
0.3)`, so this may or may not find the fixed point depending on such things as
the smoothness of your functions `JSteadyState` and `uSteadyState` and your
initial guess.

Comment: Thanks. You might want to change to `return np.array([UL2, UH2])`. This function appears to only support finding *one* fixed-point: "*Find a fixed point of the function.*". How would I go on on finding others, especially non-stable ones?

Comment: I don't know of any out-of-the-box methods for finding unstable fixed points; that seems to require mathematical analysis of the particular dynamical system.

Comment: In 1D where I was so far, I could find these simply through plotting `J(u)`, and `u(J)`. I guess 2D really makes life miserable.